# Cannot import kotlin.test.Test with gradle

Tags: kotlin, testing, gradle

I use (don't care about versions, I use platform to manage versions):

```
testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-testng")
testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common")
```

But cannot import kotlin.test.Test:

```
import kotlin.test.Test
```

`Test` shows red in IDEA, means not found, Why? something I ignored?
[image]

[image]

Comment: try to `Refresh Gradle Dependencies`, I don't know about others, but gradle acts up for me quite often.